# How to show UTC date difference?

Tags: angular

Here's what I have tried:

```js
var d = new date();
let diff = d.getTimezoneOffset();   // -330
```

I am getting Difference as -330 minutes,
however, current UTC difference is +330 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

`getTimezoneOffset()` returns the difference in minutes between UTC and your local time.

For example, if your time zone is GMT+2, -120 will be returned.

From the [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset#negative_values_and_positive_values)

> The time-zone offset is the difference, in minutes, between UTC and local time. Note that this means that the offset is positive if the local timezone is behind UTC and negative if it is ahead.

If for some reason you need the opposite, like if you get -330 and you need +330, you can always do

```
diff *= -1; // This will invert the sign of the value.
```

Answer (score 1):

> The `getTimezoneOffset()` method returns the difference, in minutes,
> between a date as evaluated in the UTC time zone, and the same date as
> evaluated in the local time zone.

(Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset)

From that you get: `UTC` - `LocalDate` = `TimeZoneOffset`.

As example: It's currently about `05:00` in Germany, we are `GMT+2`, therefore it's `03:00` in `UTC`.

```
3 - 5 = -2 * 60 = -120
```

That's really simple math. Basically you just need to `*-1` the result...